# Download scripts for Android Scripting Environment

Tags: android, android-scripting

Downloaded ASE from google code, and was looking through tutorials, and available scripts.

I found a script I wanted to try, however copy pasting it is removing all whitespace (and this is a Python script...).

Is there a simple way to download a script from the internet into the Android Scripting Environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the .py file to your SD card, under ase/scripts